# Invalid argument in jquery.js, v1.7.2, line 5875 character 5, only on IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

The page that is working fine on IE9. On IE8 I am getting the following error:

Invalid argument. 
jquery.js, line 5875 character 5. This particular line is:

`this.parentNode.insertBefore( elem, this.nextSibling );`

I am using jQuery JavaScript Library v1.7.2

Comment: The error isn't with the jQuery library, it's in your code.  Are there any other errors?  `insertBefore`... I assume that means you are calling `$(this).after()` somewhere.

Comment: Thank you
Yes, I have methods using after and insertAfter, i.e. 
$('#content').after('<div class="clear"></div>');
What is wrong in these methods?  Why this error appears only on IE8?  I am not very familiar with IE development tools – can I debug this error?

Answer (score 0):

The comment from Rocket was quite useful. 
Yes, after debugging in IE I found that the problem was in the insertAfter method.  In contrast to IE9/Mozilla the IE8 does not forgive if an element invoking insertAfter does not exist. So, something like checking for NULL is required.

So, in this case we added checking for element length, this is the example:
    if($('#footer').length) {
        $('#footer').insertAfter('#content').addClass('white center padding_half');
    }